# Operating Systems Design Race Condition

Tags: c, operating-system, race-condition

I'm working on a homework problem out of Stalling's Operating Systems: Internals and Design Principals. As such, I am not requesting an answer but any help understanding this would be helpful as I am having a tough time wrapping my head around this one. There are two processes executing:

Both processes are executing the following code:

```
shared int x;
x = 10;
while (1) 
{
    x = x - 1;
    x = x + 1;
    if (x != 10)
        printf(“x is %d”,x)
}
```

The first part of this question asked how "x is 10" could be printed, which I had no trouble tracing the logic for.

However, the second part asks how can "x is 8" be printed. Additionally it gives the hint:

"You should remember that the increment/decrements at the source language level are not done atomically, that is, the assembly language code:"

```
LD r0,X
INCR r0
STO r0,X
```

"implements the single C instruction x=x+1"

Despite the hint, I am having trouble seeing how a process can ever reach the printf section without the value being incremented back up to at least 9. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
Thread 1              Thread 2

Load x  (10)
Decr x   (9)
Store x  (9)
                      Load x  (9)
Load x   (9)
Incr x  (10)
Store x (10)
                      Decr x  (8)
                      Store x (8)
Load x   (8)
Print x  (8)
                      // ...
```

The lesson here is that if an operation is not atomic, then writes can be lost if they get overwritten.

Comment: He specifically asked to not be given the answer.

Comment: Ah, of course, I knew I was missing something mentally and it was that Load x on the right. Makes sense now, thanks for clarifying, I will accept shortly, waiting for the time limit to accept to be up.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen - Not really. He said he's `not requesting an answer` - he never requested not to be given an answer.

Comment: @Steve It is a homework problem, the answer shouldn't have been handed to the OP

Comment: @HunterMcMillen - That's a different comment than your origional one: "He specifically asked to not be given the answer." - which I was simply pointing out wasn't the case.

Comment: @HunterMcmillen Thankfully, although this did give me the answer, it also helped me understand the concept in the process. I will not simply copy what was given as I genuinely care about learning this material. +1 for the integrity of your statements, though.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the trouble you are having is coming from the fact that you are still considering

`x = x - 1` and `x = x + 1` a single operation.

Try thinking about what would happen if for instance process B interrupted process A's initial operation `x=x-1` operation by stealing the CPU, that is:

```
Process A              Process B                X             r0
-------------------------------------------------------------------
LD r0, x                                        10            10
                       LD    r0, x              10            10
                       DECR  r0                 10             9
                       STORE r0,x                9
```

Here process B interrupted process A in the middle of their decrement operation.

Comment: This was also quite helpful, thanks for taking the time to write it. +1 here as well.